# Proper implementation of IDisposable

Tags: c#, idisposable

Is there a point in securing myself against using a disposed class? I just cought myself on adding following two lines to *all* methods of my `IDisposable` class:

```
if (disposed)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to use disposed object!");
```

That just doesn't seem right.

Comment: Depends on how safe you want to be, and how you use the object. Unless you're explicitly handling that exception somewhere/everywhere, it's just going to result in either an unhandled exception or a generically-handled one, in which case you're just as well off with a null reference exception from using an object that you set to null in `Dispose()`. I see it being useful when you don't know who else could be holding on to references of your object after it's disposed (like Visual Studio's automation model), though.

Comment: Spook: Note that there is a dedicated exception type for this situation: `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: You shouldn't add this to the `Dispose` method though. The expected behavior is that it is acceptable to call `Dispose` on an object more than once.

Comment: If you really want to do it use something like PostSharp and write an aspect. Bam, zero lines of code.

Comment: No, it is the job of the class that implements IDisposable to throw that exception.  All of the .NET classes do this correctly.  You only write this code when you implement a finalizer.  Which is wrong 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best answer would be it depends.

Is the disposable class only used within a single project?

- probably no (though an assert to the same effect might not be bad)

Is the class used by anyone outside of yourself or a small team?

- probably yes

What are the side effects of accessing a disposed object?

- if it will otherwise throw exceptions the above will make your life
  easier in debugging but the end result is the same in most cases
- if it will work just fine (i.e. reallocate any necessary resources etc) then who cares really
- if it will result in undefined or unpredictable behavior that DOESN'T throw exceptions then definately, especially if you answered no and then yes to the questions above

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that what you have done is overkill.  I agree with dkackman that you should probably do as you have for those members that could fail silently but not for all.  You could just do as the Form class does and provide an IsDisposed property.  It is then the developer's responsibility to check for themselves if they don't already know that the object is disposed or not.